# Liquid simulation on GPU

Tags: simulation, gpu

I would like to implement 2D liquid simulator using GPU. I'm looking for some "simple" algorithm, that can be ported to GPU. I have this for GPU computing class. I have chosen this, because I find it very interesting. But I'm not as good in physics as I'm in programming. What do you suggest? Should I choose something else :-), or is there something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into Lennard-Jones Fluids.  It should be rather straight forward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

What aspect of liquid behaviour do you want to simulate? The answer will entirely depend on what you intend to achieve; otherwise you're likely to end up with a monstrously complicated solution that's accurate in many situations.